# Epoch time retrieved via AJAX and IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a script (getEpochTime.php) that is called via AJAX and gets the Epoch time of the server. I use PHP as back end so i used the time() command to get the epoch time.

**getEpochEpoch.php**

```
<?php

   $serverEpoch = time();

   $result = array(

            'serverEpoch' => $serverEpoch

        ); 

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Using AJAX i retrieve the server epoch time to use it for calculations:

```
$.ajax({

            url: "js/ajax/getServerEpoch.php",
            success: function(output){

                var outputFromServer = jQuery.parseJSON(output);

                var serverEpochTime = String(outputFromServer.serverEpoch);

                console.log(serverEpochTime); // this will return the server epoch time

      });
```

When i use this script with any browser *other than IE* (even Edge browser has this issue) **the script works fine**. When i try to use IE it returns an epoch time that is in the past; sometimes 20 seconds before, some other minutes or maybe hours. For some reason it doesn't read the actual time.

Meanwhile if i run the script in the URL of IE i get the correct epoch time.

Any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: well you are making a GET request so if the server is not setting the correct  no caching headers it will use what is in the cache.

Comment: I added "cache: false" inside the AJAX request but i still have the same issue..

Comment: Make the URL you are fetching unique. something like js/ajax/getServerEpoch.php?clientTime=blah where blah might be the output of a Date.getTime(). You don't have to do anything with the value received on the server side, but the unique url will prevent caching attempts by IE.

Comment: @epascarello: You are right about caching. After reloading my browser, IE worked like  a charm. Thanks!!